# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attributes' while creating a new catalogue product in django oscar

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

In views i am trying to create a new product based on  product serializer which is based on django oscar product model.I always get this error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attributes'.Following below are my code

### Views.py

```
    from serializers import CategorySerializer, ProductSerializer, ProductClassSerializer
    from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import Product, Category, ProductClass


class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing product instances.
    """
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    # create a product
    def create(self, request, format=None):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

### Serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):


    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace... also "OSCAR is proprietary instant messaging and presence information protocol by AOL." please check what the tags are actually used for before adding them.

Comment: I mean DJANGO OSCAR ecommerce platform

Comment: I faced the same problem. As I have a custom product model, I was just overriding the save method of it...there it tries to save attrs. If you do want to save attributes, you'll probably need to save this yourself, in the DRF serializer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably, somewhere else in the code, are trying to access `product.attributes`, where `product` equals `None`